# Read .inf file in nsis script

Tags: file-io, nsis

How to read a .inf file in nsis script? To be precice: I wanna read ${PRODUCT_VERSION} from a .inf file which is suppose like this: Version = 1.0.0, so I have to read it in .onInit function. Tried using FileRead or ConfigRead but failed to get what is required. I have to read a .inf file only cant change it to .txt or .config or any other. Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadINIStr should work